# Зачем курсор отскакивает на один символ назад после выхода из режима вставки?

Tags: vim

Собственно, весь вопрос -- в теме. Читал достаточно текстов, но нигде не видел ответа на него.

Ещё бывает, что изменяешь что-то, а потом курсор вообще куда-то далеко улетает. Помогает Ctrl+O (не ноль). Переход в начало копируемого текста при командах типа **yi(** вроде понятен, но тоже, собственно, "зачем"?

Может, это только у меня так? (WinXP, Cygwin 1.7.33, Vim 7.4.560).

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11402/110559

Comment: второй и третий абзацы лучше задать как отдельный вопрос о (возможной) проблеме.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[коротко](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11402/110559):

- в нормальном режиме курсор указывает **на символ** (кроме случая пустой строки).
- в режиме вставки курсор указывает **на промежуток** между символами (либо на промежуток между символом и началом/концом строки).
- при переходе из режима вставки в нормальный режим необходимо «переместить» курсор либо на «пол-сивола» вправо, либо на «пол-символа» влево.

по умолчанию выбран вариант «влево» (это поведение можно [изменить](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Prevent_escape_from_moving_the_cursor_one_character_to_the_left)), что выглядит более логичным, нежели перемещение «вправо»: во-первых, после вставки символа чаще необходима какая-нибудь манипуляция (в нормальном режиме) именно с ним, а не со следующим за ним символом, во-вторых, при нахождении в режиме вставки в конце строки (что при наборе текста случается гораздо чаще, нежели где-нибудь «в середине»), переход на «пол-символа» вправо вообще невозможен: справа-то пусто.

p.s. кстати, при обратном переходе (из нормального режима в режим вставки) возникает та же дилемма: вправо или влево пермещать курсор. но здесь есть (по умолчанию) выбор: можно нажать <kbd>i</kbd> для перемещения на «пол-символа» влево, либо <kbd>a</kbd> для перемещения вправо.