# при нажатии на i или (insert) выставить табуляцию

Tags: linux, vim

С недавних времён активно использую `vim` - очень раздражает его особенность при insert курсор перемещать всегда на начало строки.

Например есть какая-то функция

```
void foo()
{}
```

я хочу чтобы при нажатии на `i`, `o` либо `insert` курсор находящийся между фигурными скобками автоматом разтабулировался в нужное место в функции без необходимости собственно ручно выставлять табы.

Как это сделать ?

Может есть какие-то опции ?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/509385/178576

Comment: @alexanderbarakin не помогло, это все не то, что мне нужно, надо чтобы при нажатии `enter` табы выставились

Comment: по ссылке была, раз вы не заметили, не «помощь», а объснение поведения. судя по тому, что написано в первом абзаце вопроса, у вас что-то неправильно сконфигурировано. [диагностика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/532512/178576)

Comment: `set cindent`, `set autoindent`, `set smartindent`

Comment: @0andriy спасибо ! - `smartindent` вроде делает что-то похожее

Answer (score 2):

Оптимальные настройки ~/.vimrc. Либо каждый раз ручками после двоеточия (:)

```
set tabstop=2 
set shiftwidth=2 
set smarttab 
set expandtab 
set smartindent
```

- **tabstop** (по умолчанию 8) -кол-во пробелов, которыми Tab отображается в тексте
- **shiftwidth** (по умолчанию 8) - по умолчанию используется для регулирование ширины отступов в пробелах, добавляемых командами >> и <<
- **smarttab** (по умолчанию выключена) — в случае включения этой опции, нажатие Tab в начале строки (если быть точнее, до первого непробельного символа в строке) приведет к добавлению отступа, ширина которого соответствует shiftwidth
- **expandtab** - в режиме вставки заменяет символ табуляции на соответствующее количество пробелов
- **autoindent** (по умолчанию выключена) — копирует отступы с текущей строки при добавлении новой
- **smartindent** (по умолчанию выключена) — делает то же, что и autoindent плюс автоматически выставляет отступы в «нужных» местах